# Open source classification algorithms, preferably in C++

Tags: machine-learning, c++, open-source, computer-vision

I am in search of open source classification algorithms. I am  working on a computer vision project that uses classification for scene recognition. I wish to bench test a range of machine learning algorithms for the classification stage. The implementations must be on open source licenses and preferably written in C++. All and any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- dlib
  http://dlib.net/
  Machine Learning (including classification) http://dlib.net/ml.html
  Examples: http://dlib.net/multiclass_classification_ex.cpp.html
- Shark
  http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/
  http://image.diku.dk/shark/sphinx_pages/build/html/rest_sources/tutorials/tutorials.html
- Shogun - A Large Scale Machine Learning Toolbox
  http://shogun-toolbox.org/
  http://shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/current/methods.html
  http://shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/current/libshogun_examples.html
  // **Note:** the aforementioned example has me rather worried in that it seems this library is not following best practices of [modern C++](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/): in particular, raw pointers and manual `new`/`delete` are usually a bad practice without a specific, well-motivated need (that I find lacking in the context of the presented examples). See: http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/
- Vowpal Wabbit
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowpal_Wabbit
  https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki
  Written in C++, can be used as a library; examples:
  https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tree/master/library
  // **Note:** manual invocations of `VW::initialize` and `VW::finish` operating on a raw pointer `vw*` raise concerns similar to the ones above; example:
  https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/library/library_example.cc

For more, see also Machine Learning Open Source Software:
http://mloss.org/software/language/c__/

You may also find the following of use:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167024/fastest-general-machine-learning-library
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915341/which-machine-learning-library-to-use

Answer (score 3):

What you really need is [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) . OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision Library) is an open source computer vision and machine learning software library. It has C++, C, Python and Java interfaces and supports Windows, Linux, Android and Mac OS.

You may find there lots of solutions for computer vision recognition problems.

Answer (score 0):

LIBSVM, de facto standard for SVM learning (BSD license):

- [home page](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)
- implemented in `C`, so trivial to use in `C++`
- interfaces in various languages available, including R ([kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/index.html)), Python ([scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/)), ...

---

Shameless self advertisement: EnsembleSVM

- [home page](http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/stadius/ensemblesvm/)
- [github](https://github.com/claesenm/EnsembleSVM)
- implemented in `C++11`

EnsembleSVM is a toolbox for fast nonlinear learning with SVMs. Licensed under LGPL v3. Some basic info is available in our [paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume15/claesen14a/claesen14a.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

VlFeat http://www.vlfeat.org/ is great computer vision library written in pure C.